# Embedding a very large file efficiently into a Go binary

Tags: docker, go

I have a pretty large file (~ 1GB) that I want to embed into a Go binary. The file is a tar.gz of some exported Docker images. The purpose of embedding this file into the binary is to ensure that the Go program and the Docker images can't be out of sync and to make it trivial to deploy this binary as a single file.

There seem to be a few libraries that can do that, I tried [packr](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr) and it did work in general. But unfortunately when I looked at the resource usage of the program while piping this embedded file into `docker load`, my program used up to 6 GB of RAM for this process.

The code for embedding and using the file was the following:

```
imageBox := packr.NewBox("./images")
cmd := exec.Command("docker", "load")
imageFileHandle, _ := imageBox.Open("image.tar.gz")
cmd.Stdin = imageFileHandle
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
_ := cmd.Run()
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong in how I wire up the embedded file to the execution of `docker load` here, or if this library is simply not designed for the kind of thing I'm doing here. I looked a bit more around for tools to embed files in Go, but they seem to be mostly targeted at something like static assets for a web server, so a bunch of relatively small files. I didn't find anything on efficient embedding of very large blobs of data.

Is there a way to embed a single large file in a go binary and pipe it into a command efficiently without loading it entirely into memory?

Comment: Your code is stream (reader/writer) oriented, so I'm guessing this is an internal deficiency of `packr`. Perhaps open an issue with that project?

Comment: If your only goal is to ensure that your file and binary remain in sync, I'd suggest storing an MD5 sum or SHA1, rather than the entire file.

Comment: Why choose this particular approach?  My first instincts to getting a particular image running on a particular system would be (1) put the image on a Docker registry (either run your own, use something public like Docker Hub, or something cloud-hosted like AWS ECR), or else (2) distribute the `docker save` tarball alongside the installer (and probably use a shell script and not a Go program to launch it).

Comment: @DavidMaze the goal is to simplify the distribution and deployment as much as possible. The alternative plan is to distribute the images alongside the program, if this turns out to be too difficult to implement efficiently.

Comment: I'd rather go with sidecar container verified by a md5 or similar. Either compose / docker stack or kubernetes deployment. Depending on environment.

Comment: Looking through the code, packr indeed copies the embedded file at least once [in buildFile](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packd/blob/27cb1d7/file.go#L121), which is eventually called by Open. Find [copies too](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr/blob/bded308/box.go#L111), so one has to assume this is on purpose to prevent accidental modification of the embedded data. I'm not too familiar with packr, but presumaby Box.AddBytes is called *somewhere* in your code. Perhaps you can just create a bytes.NewReader instead.